# Crystal reports surpressed subreport queries

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, subreport

Will a surpressed subreport still run it's queries to the database in the background?

I have a report with 8 conditionally surpressed subreports. Each query in the subreports takes appr 500ms to run.
Only one subreport Is visible at once, but still my report takes about 3 seconds to run.

I thought surpressed subreports didn't run it's queries. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the queries are still executed even if supressed.

I'm not sure about this but try:

1 . Inside of sub report , right click on Database Fields - Log On or Off Server

2 . Select the dataset you need and choose Log Off.